# Do not display a remote notification based on custom data

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I would like to give users the option to enable/disable certain types of notifications.  For example, turn on push notifications for private messages, but turn off for public posts.  I was wondering if it was possible to do this on the client side after receiving the APN (in didReceiveRemoteNotification), I wasn't sure if the notification is already displayed before didReceiveRemoteNotification is called.

Currently I am using OneSignal to send push notifications, and am sending them with content-available true (1). This correctly triggers didReceiveRemoteNotification while the app is in the background. Based on the data I sent, I want to show or not show any banner push notification at all.

Here is what I have attempted so far, I'm able to get the data I need but I haven't been able to figure out how to tell the iDevice to not display it at all:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("****this happened****")
    print("\(userInfo)")
    if let customData = userInfo["custom"] as? [String: Any] {
        if let additionalData = customData["a"] as? [String: Any] {
            if let notificationType = additionalData["notification_type"] as? String {
                if notificationType == "follow" {
                    print("do not want to display")
                    if var apsData = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: Any] {
                        apsData.removeValue(forKey: "content-available")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("dispaying this notification")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The other way I have thought about it is to store the notifications settings for users into my database, and when a user is sending a push notification to check against those to see whether or not they should even send a push. I would just like to see if it is possible to tackle this without adding more database querying.

EDIT: I also use OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions and noticed that this gets called before didReceiveRemoteNotification in handleNotificationReceived, I am wondering if it is possible to stop the push notification here

```
if receivedNotification?.payload != nil {
     if receivedNotification?.payload.additionalData != nil {
         if let data = receivedNotification?.payload.additionalData["notification_type"] as? String {
             if data == "follow" {
                print("do not display this")
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead I recommend filtering on your server as sending a notification to all devices (just to omit them from being displayed) has down sides including; extra battery drain and `content-available` notifications do not work when the user swipes away the app.

You can use `mutable-content` instead which will fire your [`UNNotificationServiceExtension`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) but this only works on iOS 10 and you still need to take battery into consideration.

You can get the device's OneSignal player id by calling [IdsAvailable](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk#section--idsavailable-) where you can store this on your back end. Then you can then use `include_player_ids` on the [create notification REST API call](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification) to target only the users who should receive the notification.

Comment: I had a feeling this might be the solution I had to go with, I was hoping Apple or the OneSignal iOS SDK had something similar to their NotificationExtenderService for Android, guess I'll have to implement it this way then!  Thanks!

Comment: @Hellojeffy I added `mutable-content` to my answer for a 2nd option. Even with `NotificationExtenderService` on Android it is still recommend to use `include_player_ids` like iOS as this will keep the device from waking in the first place and will save on the user's battery.